# How to create a translator with dictionaries using Composition API

Tags: vuejs3

I'm trying to understand how to use `Composition API`. In this simple app I'm trying to implement a reactive translator with multiple dictionaries. Basically, what I want to do is to click on a button and change a language on a page. Right now clicking it does nothing.
Here's where I'm stuck, please check it on [flems.io](https://flems.io/#0=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-SG43uzKwfqVGq576DcE58qOwlRlt54HpzODP4t0VE0Gx+NWV35Kuer3EOQ12rVT6NmedxtOHW6GbQOCTpYAZlQACY9gcjmwONg8IQBA8xPAOC6L9j2-pILGsPa29yXTZE6jvTO5wGetyi7ZdFx+RxsTNCBLQuK4ggdblhzjPQbFwdDfynAtewA2sFwbSowIIwZtS1LlvDYeAuCEJAwElfR9EAutagacYWjaAoOgYLoIECD9IwYhiXQYCAAHdgK7bEqIoVMVx+JQFLlGE5AAfjlElITkakYW5fRpNTJj8JAxtwRE8TwIgMsGNI-RSNI3Q-VwWBQVtCAL3BC9YVwFghCNeAoQAYg0LA4Q3e4hEDKheI4JImCSaBNzmHcOAARn3XcD22XZ9iLUg8gYAoaHoEBmDPdAZCBLIRIADzvUg434dAeHgLA6NcVwjSwApyiciLXAqiAsl3XAthGjZAlgXAUq2OI3n63FynMWKoFuAR4C9LATnAZyKCwO9HCLRwgA)

**index.html**

```
<div id="app">
  <div>Hello: {{ Hello }}</div>
  <div>World: {{ World }}</div>
  <button @click="changeLangButtonClickHandler">Change lang</button>
</div>
```

**App.js**

```
const App = {
  setup () {
    const { dictionary, changeLanguage, language } = useTranslator()
    return { ...dictionary.value, changeLanguage, language }
  },
  methods: {
    changeLangButtonClickHandler () {
      const newLanguage = this.language === 'en' ? 'ru' : 'en'
      this.changeLanguage(newLanguage)
    }
  }
}

Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

**translator.js**

```
const language = Vue.ref('en')
const dictionaries = Vue.ref({
  ru: {
    Hello: 'Привет',
    World: 'Мир'
  },
  en: {
    Hello: 'Hello',
    World: 'World'
  }
})

function useTranslator () {
  const dictionary = Vue.computed(() => {
    return dictionaries.value[language.value]
  })
  function changeLanguage (lang) {
    language.value = lang
  }
  return { dictionary, changeLanguage, language }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if you're using `return { ...dictionary.value, changeLanguage, language }` the `...dictionary.value` will cease being reactive. That's why switching to `...dictionary` and `distionary.Hello` works.

---

*on a side note...*, you don't even need a `useTranslator` function, you can just export the functions and variables like this

```js
// private
const dictionaries = Vue.ref({
  ru: {
    Hello: "Привет",
    World: "Мир"
  },
  en: {
    Hello: "Hello",
    World: "World"
  }
});
// public
export const language = Vue.ref("en");
export const dictionary = Vue.computed(() => {
  return dictionaries.value[language.value];
});
export const changeLanguage = lang => {
  language.value = lang;
};
```

The `useSomethingSomething()` function is helpful if you want to pass aspects of the component or a variable to the function. Or have a stylistic preference.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [working](https://flems.io/#0=N4IgzgpgNhDGAuEAmIBcJ4CcCGA7MU28A9pgHQBWYIANCAGYCWM1qA2qLtgLYRohkAFvG5RaIWMVyJp-ADxJGANwAEjJAF4AOiGwAHPToB8W3CpULlRgBLQoxVCuDAVihIynZMATzK2o9ioAvkFyAPSKSiZmFpFGAOqkUEiOzq6M7p4+ZImYycGhEVam5nIARgCu8CRmAAKwUBkA1toSgngA5hAAMp0AQlU1AMKNsE3WeEgwmMZD7bhdKoQL4ZXVUtHhceKQMJn4-ABMqIcAHCBBNJw8fOhYeAREpJTUdJLSELLo72DwS50VbCLDQqABqFQgZEwEHoAAoAOSfeEASlMPz+bngHi4mEYEDAKhB4Mh0Ow7iUEFhwBKKkwFVSNPM-nsjnhgHwQQACIIAOEEATCCAVhBAEIg8JojJUuWSrMAOCBcjnwmmXGmfBkxJl2BwqeHM4jC0XilIavVymJBUxBVG4Uz0Cq4fYqCqQAAqOHwhBImBUsORThp6PS+y83kJYIhZEk3D0VWQsM9hKM3pVtIg8AqmDMmOxXjxYDYyw6gK6ZCU2CgEIAuvLzeYrTasVIVLB5l1egt8xAPbmvdSE7nW4XixCg7n5TTocnU04-bWcd4aPXGz0AUCILOe0vgqbTDtoHAp6wQABGAAsqH3+4AtEeTgBmC5XEBcXj8ACCBhe4neMng-F9L70Qa75iQMmf4xgB5j1lIvwTumWQznOnQLi2S4rouixBEG9oQE6DyuqQnqiqOKZmC4MHTrODYIc2ebIf8SFofKIoxLw8CCMQSBgMq4HwQsiEdAM6y4CMzQTLgUwQO6oGiuYvq4BAADuVGtkGLGMGAZCrsCGggoiuDwioAD8Gp0nprJIlJKgqWpFE8YpS6wrJCmoRAlbgSaxobhauDEqGpKIL+sK-siZDcMQ1rwAiADE+h6Cim5vMQ4bMOJ-BlNgZTQFuey7vwV7XhcpZ0I0uBNKwHD3jc-BKBCtSyQAHl+dApmI6DCPAegcWEYTWnoTQdKGCVhFVEC1FeZAAAzjWemCwGQ+5jUUvyDSGHT2KlUBvnQ8DeHotzgLAuJ6F+QSlkEQA) version.

I replaced `<div>Hello: {{ Hello }}</div>` with `<div>Hello: {{ dictionary.Hello }}</div>` in `index.html`

And also replaced `{ ...dictionary.value, changeLanguage, language }` with `return { dictionary, changeLanguage, language }` in `setup` function

The issue had something to do with how reactivity system works